Solve for probability of 0 successes where number of attempts is a random variable with unknown distribution
I am interested in solving the following problem:
Imagine we have some event A that can occur with probability p, let q = 1 - p. The number of attempts we have for event A to occur is itself a random variable X, which can take values 0,1,2,3,..n. The probability for the event A to occur is independent for each attempt. We do not know the distribution of X, but may be able to solve for it. I am looking to solve for the probability that event A never occurs, call the event that A never occurs B. I believe this can be expressed as:
$prob(B) = prob(B | X = 0) + prob(B | X = 1) + ... + prob(B | X = n)$
$prob(B) = q^0 ⋅ prob(X = 0) + q^1 ⋅ prob(X = 1) + ... + q^n ⋅ prob(X = n)$
$prob(B) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}q^{k}⋅prob(X = k)$
I am wondering if there is another way to determine prob(B), since solving for prob(X = k) is proving to be quite difficult without knowing its distribution up front.
For a concrete example consider the following game:
We roll a die, we start with 5 initial rolls. If we roll a 1 or a 3 we win an additional +1 or +3 rolls respectively. The game is over when we run out of rolls. Let the event A be rolling a 6 and our random variable X be the total number of rolls played. Our generic problem above becomes: what is the probability we finish the game having never rolled a 6? In this specific example if we can solve for the probability to roll exactly k times, we can solve for the overall probability of never rolling a 6.
My first approach in this specific case was to try to set up the number of rolls as a random walk in 2 dimensions, with times rolled (n) on the x axis and rolls remaining (r) on the y axis. If we roll a 1 we move from (n,r)->(n+1,r) since we win back the roll we just took, similarly, if we roll a 3 we move from (n,r)->(n+1,r+2) and if we roll any other number we move from (n,r)->(n+1,r-1). We essentially have an absorbing barrier at r = 0 as that is when the game "ends". Here is an illustration of one such possible walk:

Each of these steps would have some probabilities associated with them and a recursive relation could potentially be set up and solved for to get a closed form solution for the probability to roll exactly k times and solve for the overall chance of never rolling a 6. Is there some better way to solve for never rolling a 6 without needing to solve for prob(X = k)? If not, is this the most viable approach to solve for the underlying distribution of random variable X?
